# Filter out tests from Jenkins Matrix combinations

Tags: jenkins, matrix, groovy

**Setup:**

My tests are split out on 3 axes in the Configuration Matrix:

- site : Site1, Site2
- browser : Chrome, Firefox, Safari
- test : Test1, Test2, Test3

Groovy Script Matrix Executor Strategy is selected with the following piece of groovy script:

```
combinations.each{
             result[it.browser] = result[it.browser] ?: []    
         result[it.browser] << it
}

return [ result, true]
```

And in the end, the final matrix looks like this:
First image from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVOoM.jpg).

Now, when I add a new test, I only want to have just for Site1 for example, so in the end the matrix should look like the second image from the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVOoM.jpg) above.

The help mentions about a Combination Filter, where, if I understood correctly, I could do:

```
!(site=="Site2" && test=="Test4")
!(site=="Site3" && test=="Test4")
```

Using these statements with the combinations above, didn't seemed to work.

It can be done? Can someone point what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the combination filter with the groovy matrix execution strategy. It only shows up due to the way the UI has evolved over time.

I think you can use [the matrix combination plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Combinations+Plugin) with the groovy Execution strategy and then pick the ones you want.

Alternatively, you can adjust your groovy script. if you don't add a combination in, it wont be run

untested

```
combinations.each{
     if(['Site2', 'Site3'].contains(it.site) && it.test == 'Test4')
         return

     result[it.browser] = result[it.browser] ?: []    
     result[it.browser] << it
}

return [ result, true]
```

Disclaimer:
Matrix Groovy Execution Strategy is my plugin